# Is it possible to impersonate the datasource when rendering an RDLX in ComponentOne ActiveReports WebService?

Tags: silverlight, activereports, componentone

I'm currently implementing a report viewer in SilverLight, and I want to know how to impersonate the datasource when rendering an RDLX in ComponentOne ActiveReports WebService?

Answer (score 0):

In order to impersonate the datasource in rdlx file, you may refer to the two walkthroughs discussed in the documentation.
http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/arWLKDocumentWebService.html
http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/arWLKDataSetWebService.html

Regards,
Mohita